# jQuery.appear fires only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using [jQuery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) to check if an element is in view-port. The plugin works great. But it fires only once. I want it to fire every time when the element is in view-port.

```
$("#creative_thinkers").appear(function () {
    console.log("Only fires once");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear/blob/master/README.md):

```
$('#creative_thinkers').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
});
```

I checked on the [demo](http://morr.github.io/appear.html) and it's seems to fire every time.

Comment: Well it seems to work fine on the demo. Looks like something is wrong with your code and I can't help you without more informations.

Comment: I used it but it does not fire even once. Any idea? $('#creative_thinkers').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) { console.log("not firing at all"); })

Comment: The Readme is rather poor. In my reading, it doesn't say that `$('someselector').appear(fn)` and `$('someselector').on('appear', fn)` behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery one http://api.jquery.com/one

```
$('#creative_thinkers').one('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
});
```